# Stop web page from capturing my finger movements on Android

Tags: android, chrome, user-interface

I am trying to edit my weebly site, but it has too many pages on the page bar. As a result, i need to scroll down the pages frame to see all the pages. The problem is that Weebly interprets my scrolling finger movement as a movement to re-arrange page order. I suppose any website would have this issue if there is scrolling and item movement combined in the same frame.

So basically i need to know how to temporarily prevent this frame in Chrome from capturing my finger press and drag movement so that Chrome can get that gesture and scroll the frame.

Unfortunately i don't have a computer so i have to figure this out now with my phone.

Thanks!